# Xamarin Forms and Prism, error when calling NavigationPage

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm trying to implement a login flow (firstly showing the LoginPage) and the Login Page has a Command that the user can click to create an account (this is a NavigationPage), so the flow is LoginPage -> NewAccountPage (with button bar to navigate back to LoginPage).

```
In App.xaml.cs I have:
NavigationService.NavigateASync("LoginPage");  //I'm not sure if the LoginPage should be in NavigationStack, maybe be presented in Modal way
```

In LoginPageViewModel, I have a Command that simply call

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("NewAccountPage");
```

When the user press this button to create an account, the NewAccountPage is properly called but I get an error when the code flow finish to call the NavigationAsync("NewAccountPage");

The error is something like this :

```
Unhandled Exception:System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements ocurred
```

I have no idea how to handle with this, could someone review if I'm making any mistake?

Comment: unfortunately, there is not enough information to help. Also you have conflicting information in your description as you are not using a NavigationPage anywhere, but you say you are.  Please clarify your issue and provide much more detail.

Comment: This has been answered on your other post on the Xamarin.Forms forum: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97823/prism-and-navigation

Answer (score 0):

```
 NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MasterDetailsPage/NavigationPage/MainPage");
```

Comment: Although this anwer tries to reply the question, it would be better if it had a description on how that code addresses the problem.